# What is different between while(aPointer) and a if(aPointer) in C++?

Tags: c++, arraylist

I'm working on a print function and my original codes is like

```
void print1(const char *cp)
{
    while(cp)
    {
        if(*cp)
        {
            cout << *cp++ << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

it would never stop until I changed it to

```
void print1(const char *cp)
{
    if(cp)
    {
        while(*cp)
        {
            cout << *cp++ << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

I got a little confused about this code, actually it's a code in C++Primer. Did while and if consider the same thing? But why the first one cannot stop? Is that because there is a pointer points to the last location but it has nothing in it, the while would be true forever but will never get into the if?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, the loop runs until the pointer itself becomes null, which it never does (instead, it's eventually incremented past the end of the buffer, whereupon the program exhibits undefined behavior).

In the second example, the loop runs until the character pointed to becomes zero - which it does once the advancing pointer reaches the end of a nul-terminated string.

Comment: Is that because at first function, the while(cp) is to see if the pointer exists, if(*cp) is to see the location where the pointer points has sth in it?

Comment: at the second function, the if(cp) is to see if pointer exists, while(*cp) is to see the location where the pointer points has sth in it AND sth does not equal to '\0'.

Comment: @Goessi The logic of the first function is simply messed up. The `if`-statement in the 2nd function is there to avoid dereferencing a `nullptr` inside the controlled statement which would be undefined behaviour.